# Ignore triggers when gathering dependencies with SMO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, smo

I have a system that transfers data between two databases with identical schemas (for development purposes).

The SMO dependency walker works great except for triggers. If I am getting a list of dependencies, I don't care if a trigger introduces a dependency on another table because the trigger will not be executing during the transfer. It's especially annoying if there are circular dependencies.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to ignore triggers in the dependency walking step. I've tried a few things, with no luck:

- Not including triggers in the list of objects when calling `DiscoverDependencies`. I'm only including tables anyway.
- Using `FilterCallbackFunction` on `DependencyWalker`. This seems to do absolutely nothing.

This is the code I have now:

```
var tablesToLoad = scripter.WalkDependencies(new DependencyWalker(server).DiscoverDependencies(filteredTables, DependencyType.Parents))
                           .Where(n => n.Urn.Type != "UnresolvedEntity")
                           .Select(n => server.GetSmoObject(n.Urn))
                           .OfType<Table>()
                           .ToArray();
```

The variable `filteredTables` contains a list of tables that I want to use for transferring data. The result is all the tables, in their dependency order, that need to be transferred, with dependencies between tables included (including other tables that need to be pulled in to keep foreign key relationships from failing).

EDIT: I want to reiterate that the problem isn't whether triggers are executing or not. The problem is that SMO looks into triggers when determining dependency order for loading tables. So if a trigger references another table, regardless of whether the statements that reference that table would actually ever execute in the trigger, that reference is considered for dependency resolution. I don't want triggers to be used for dependency resolution *at all*. How do I get SMO to ignore triggers without having to drop them from the database? That's my question.

Comment: The table does not exist in the destination database?

Comment: The table does exist. I'm just transferring data.

Comment: just an idea, but what about if you transfer your data to a intermediate database server that have only the schema (and no triggers). After that from this intermediate, send to your final database server.

Comment: I guess that can work, though it means that I have to have a database that just exists to hold a partial schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the only way to achieve this would be to remove the triggers and then re-add them after the dependency walker completes.

First, get the list of triggers and drop them --

```
var triggers = database.Triggers;
foreach (var trigger in triggers)
{
    trigger.Drop();
}
```

Build the dependency tree --

```
var tablesToLoad = scripter.WalkDependencies(new DependencyWalker(server).DiscoverDependencies(filteredTables, DependencyType.Parents))
                           .Where(n => n.Urn.Type != "UnresolvedEntity")
                           .Select(n => server.GetSmoObject(n.Urn))
                           .OfType<Table>()
                           .ToArray();
```

Recreate the triggers --

```
foreach (var trigger in triggers)
{
    trigger.Create();
}
```

Comment: That's what I have now. I was hoping to avoid, but if SMO is not flexible enough, then I suppose I'll have to stick with it.

Comment: I know it's ugly, but as of now I don't see another way. If this is the correct solution I would suggest answering your own question and marking it complete such that others in the community would benefit from your findings. I will upvote your answer.

Comment: your answer basically has what I've done, so I'll let you get the internet points. Thanks for trying anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 SQL Server stored procedures, one for disabling and the other for enabling the triggers.  Before loading your tables, call the disable trigger stored procedure using the [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.110).aspx) class and when the table load completes, use `SQLCommand` to execute the enable trigger procedure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think disabling the triggers will stop SMO from considering the triggers when determining dependency order. I don't really care if the triggers execute or not, but I do care that the tables are loaded in the right order, and I can't get that order if SMO considers the triggers for dependency order.